# Jquery checking each object key

Tags: jquery, object

I have an object like this:

```
  obj {"name" : "html"
       "name2" : "html"
       "name3" : "html"}
```

I want to check every a element on a page, and if the object name matches the text in the a element, insert the html for that name.

How can I do this?

Html:

```
 <div id="paged_view_content">
 <div class="vis_item" align="center">
<a href="/game.php? t=487615717&village=22979&mode=combined&group=5043&screen=overview_villages"   class="group_tooltip">[00 ATT-BUNK]</a>
<a href="/game.php?    t=487615717&village=22979&mode=combined&group=1276&screen=overview_villages"        class="group_tooltip">[01 ATT-NOR]</a></div></div>
```

My "name"s will exactly match names like [01 ATT-NOR] :)

I can check the names with Indexof, but how do I check for each name in the object, and thenn add the html if it matches?

Comment: can you share the html sample of the elements also

Comment: Where do you want to add the html if it matches?

Comment: Just a simple prepend. I had it working but then I got two icons in one place <.< And now its broken again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#paged_view_content a').text(function (i, text) {
    text = $.trim(text);
    var key = text.substring(1, text.length - 1);
    return obj[key]
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YLpcQ/)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljqi470tpt5cf4e/Screenshot%202014-02-03%2014.21.14.png   it's not really working =/ I had it working with your previous answer, but then I had two icons in one place

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5twjwjd6jw5c2fl/Screenshot%202014-02-03%2014.28.23.png   As you can see, two icons in one place.

Comment: @user3227070 in the loaded html also you are using `$` directly to refer jQuery change them also

Comment: @user3227070 please edit the fiddle I shared to recreate the problem